# Jar dependencies to use jetty httpclient

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, jetty, jetty-httpclient

I want to use the jetty [httpclient](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/HttpClient)(in netbeans) but have the least number of jar dependencies. I know I can import all jars from the jetty lib folder to my project but I would like to know what the minimum number of dependencies are and how you did find this out? Our there tools to find jar dependencies?

Comment: Do it the hard way. Remove all JAR's, run the application, analyze the classname in `NoClassDefFoundError`, locate the JAR containing the class, add the desired JAR back and redo until you don't get the error anymore :) The easy way would be using Maven2 or some kind of dependency management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay after a little bit more googling I found this [link](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/archive-details/org/eclipse/jetty/aggregate/jetty-client/7.0.1.v20091125/jetty-client-7.0.1.v20091125.jar) with the correct aggregrate jar to play with httpclient.

Comment: Link is dead =(

Comment: lol post of 2010 so it is not really strange I guess. If you find correct link please add extra answer with correct link

Comment: Therefore the house rule: don't answer with links ;-) I never found the link, but this is what I use now: `
 org.eclipse.jetty.client;version="9.2.12",
 org.eclipse.jetty.client.api;version="9.2.12",
 org.eclipse.jetty.client.util;version="9.2.12",
 org.eclipse.jetty.http;version="8.1.16",
 org.eclipse.jetty.util;version="9.2.12",
 org.eclipse.jetty.util.component;version="9.2.12",
 org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl;version="9.2.12",`